# How do I substitute text with variable content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With the `substitute` statement I am able to replace text.
I have however a situation in which I don't know how to solve it.
Is there a formula-solution to accomplish the following:

currently:
A1 | BLABLABLA `WITH 15% OR MORE` BLABLABLA

expected outcome
A1 | BLABLABLA `WITH NOT LESS THAN 15%` BLABLABLA

**Note** that the "BLABLABLA" text is variable and so is the percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formila I developed for you has the original text in A2. Please paste it on the same tab where you want the modified string to appear.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(MID(A2,SEARCH("with *% or more",A2)+5,10),FIND("%",MID(A2,SEARCH("with *% or more",A2)+5,10)) -1)&"% or more","at least "&LEFT(MID(A2,SEARCH("with *% or more",A2)+5,10),FIND("%",MID(A2,SEARCH("with *% or more",A2)+5,10)) -1)&"%")
```

Below is the complete history of development where you can see the steps taken. This will be useful if you ever want to modify it.

[image]